# JavaScript .bind mehtod doesn't catch up a context

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In sendTo method of user I tried to bind earlier defined function and send this.name as the first argument. But if i try console logging, this.name returns undefind. How to correctcly bind context of user's object to sendTo() mehtod?

```
function sendFrom(from, to, text) {
    console.log(this);
    return `${from}'s packet --> ${to}  \nmessage: ${text}`;
}

let user = {
    name: "Alex",
    sendTo: sendFrom.bind(this, this.name),
}


user.sendTo = user.sendTo.bind(user);

console.log(user.sendTo("John", "some message"));
```

```
{}
undefined's packet --> John  
message: some message
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `user.sendTo.bind(this, user)` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille If i use user.sendTo.bind(this, user), it seems to bind whole user object to second argument of sendFrom()
`undefined's packet --> [object Object]`

Comment: Object literals do not create a scope, i.e. `this` doesn't refer to the object literal (the object doesn't even exist at that point). This has nothing to do with using `.bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can achieve expected behavior by not using any bindings:

```js
function sendFrom(to, text) {
    console.log(this);
    return `${this.name}'s packet --> ${to}  \nmessage: ${text}`;
}

let user = {
    name: "Alex",
    sendTo: sendFrom
}

console.log(user.sendTo("John", "some message"));
```

But if you want to execute the user's method somewhere else  that when binding comes into play:

```js
let alexeSendTo = user.sendTo
alexesSendTo('John', 'Hey John!') // it will loose Alex's user context link

let alexeSendTo = user.sendTo.bind(user)
alexesSendTo('John', 'Hey John!') // now it is marked as Alex message
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to understand how the context works in binded function. So this example is good, but it is not what i want to achieve. But thank you for your answer anyways!

Comment: @shevy have a look at my answer for an explanation. To let you know, there is not a need of binding here and this might not be the best example. Dmitrii's code is the correct and simplest way to do it

Comment: @TusharShahi Ok, thank you.
p.s. I was just experementing with JS, most likely i will never face this example in production. I just wanted to have a clearier view on JS context behaviour. :)

Answer (score 2):

To undersand why this does not work you have to look at the `user` object:

`sendTo: sendFrom.bind(this, this.name),`

This property inside `user` is what is causing the issue. When this code is **run** `this` belongs to the window object and not the user.

So finally `sendTo` is a method with context as `window` and first param as `window.name`

That is why `console.log(this)` returns the window object.

When you do this:
`console.log(user.sendTo("John", "some message"));`

You are adding the params `"John"` and `"some message"` after the already appended param.

So finally params become:

**from, to, text** -> `window.name`(undefined in your case), John, some message

Anytime you are using `this` in this code it is referring to window. There is actually no way to understand **binding** here and this example is not where you should be using **bind**

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I figured out why it works like that. But can you please explain how can i apply a current object's context within it?

Comment: @shevy: [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/218196)

Comment: @shevy as mentioned in the above answer comment, adding bind and all here is over engineering and will not show you the way bind works. Look at Felix's link